# A ListActivity and a Button: mission impossible?

Tags: android, button, listactivity

I have a `ListActivity` so as to fill the content of a `ListView` with an array of a Class I created.

No problem with that, but I have a Button placed underneath the ListView like this: [Adding a button underneath a listview on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342931/adding-a-button-underneath-a-listview-on-android)

And the problem is: how do I set a onClickListener for that button?

I tried this:

```
public class showTasks extends ListActivity implements OnClickListener{

Button addTaskButton;
Task[] tasks = {...};

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.show_tasks);
    setListAdapter(new TaskAdapter());

    addTaskButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.addTaskButton);
}

public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id){

    Intent i=new Intent(this,showTask.class);
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putSerializable("task", tasks[position]);
    i.putExtras(b);
    startActivity(i);
}



//adapting a task to be viewable as a list of instances of the layout Task
class TaskAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Task>{
    TaskAdapter(){
        super(showTasks.this, R.layout.task, tasks);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        View task=convertView;

        if(task==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

            task=inflater.inflate(R.layout.task, parent, false);
        }


        //now, let's define the Task variables and data
        TextView taskName=(TextView)task.findViewById(R.id.taskName);
        taskName.setText(tasks[position].name);

        TextView deadline=(TextView)task.findViewById(R.id.deadline);
        deadline.setText(tasks[position].deadline);

        TextView importance=(TextView)task.findViewById(R.id.importance);
        importance.setText(tasks[position].importance);

        TextView urgency=(TextView)task.findViewById(R.id.urgency);
        urgency.setText(tasks[position].urgency);

        return(task);
    }
}

public void onClick(View view) {
    if(view==addTaskButton){
        Intent i=new Intent(this,addTask.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}

public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

Just look at the last part: to begin with, it doesn't let me have a void onClick(View view), it has to be onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which).

But it doesn't even get there, because as soon as I get to
    addTaskButton.setOnClickListener((android.view.View.OnClickListener) this);
it dies!

So, how can I have a `ListView` and a Button in the same `ListActivity`?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong dialog... make sure your import statement says:

```
import android.view.OnClickListener;
```

instead of

```
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
```