# Surprise!! Another ListView dead end.. LV won't display

Tags: java, android, xml

So I've been working awhile and can't seem to figure out this darn ListView business..
I had it working in another app but when I copy pasted (i know) it didn't work.
So after looking around for about 6 hours I decided to come here.

This code executes with no error but doesn't display anything on the ListView. what I eventually want to do is add a button on the bottom, seperate from the ListView.

(P.S) I made the 8 spaces like I should have, I won't know why the code is not showing, that's about my luck today.

Here is the Java code:

```
   Edit: posted the wrong files, here is the right code. (broken)

    public class ShittyAdapter extends ListActivity{
Context context;
public ShittyAdapter(){
    context = this;

}
//variables go here


String[] temp;
ArrayList<SearchResults> results = new ArrayList<SearchResults>();
SearchResults sr1 = new SearchResults();

// called when the activity starts
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    init();
    this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
            R.layout.searchbutton, R.id.label, convertAryList()));

}
@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes" })
private ArrayList prepareList(){
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    sr1 = new SearchResults();
    sr1.setName(prefs.getString("name", "0"));
    ...
    sr1.setEmail(prefs.getString("email", "0"));
    return results;
}

public String[] convertAryList(){
    prepareList();
    temp = new String[] {...args...};
    System.out.println(temp);
    return temp;

}

@Override 
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id){
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    //get clicked item
    Object o = this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    String keyword = o.toString();
    Toast.makeText(this, "You selected: "+ keyword, 
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    switch(position){
    case 0: //food
         Intent intent = new Intent(context, ShittyAdapter.class);
            startActivity(intent);  
    break;
    //ToDo cases for others
    default:        
    }



}
```

}

here is the xml:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView android:text="@+id/TextView01" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/label"
    android:textSize="30px"></TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you show the getView method in your Adapter? I rarely ever use te default viewer, but if you do you have to tell the ListView a few things. Thanks

Comment: Can you show the code that actually populates the list (prepareList())? Also post CustomBaseAdapter please

Comment: So, wait: the `laidout.xml` file, which supposedly contains the layout for the `ListView` items, is composed by a single `TextView`, but the `ViewHolder` in your adapter sets the text value for at least two `TextView`s that it takes from... where, exactly?

Comment: yea, i got my files all crossed up.. i'm esperimenting with different lsit views.. i'll organize this better. i've been up for over 24 hours working on this :(

Comment: Now, how to put a button on footer? i'm actually back where i started

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342931/adding-a-button-underneath-a-listview-on-android  question answered here

Answer (score 1):

Try the following things in your CustomBaseAdapter.

```
getCount()
   return 10;

getView()
    View v = new View();
    //Fill width, 100px height
    v.setLayoutParams(new ListView.LayoutParams(ListView.LayoutParam.FILL_PARENT,100));     
    v.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN); //Ord a random color
    return v;
```

Sorry for the short hand, but if your adapter only contains that, it should make the list 10 green rectangles.

From there you can start doing more advanced thngs.

Comment: thanks all, found the solution here..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342931/adding-a-button-underneath-a-listview-on-android now to expand upon this.